# ''cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time'' error upon querying

Tags: database, google-bigquery

There are four fields with multiple rows. I wish to append these rows. Is there a way to do it?

Sample data:

[image: Here's an Example (Sample Data)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I see only two fields in your example*
Below should work for them

```
SELECT
  Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Nickname) AS Nicknames
FROM Yourtable
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: That works. Is there a way to add a delimiter along with it?

Comment: sure. see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#group_concat - for ex. GROUP_CONCAT(Nickname, '|')